# nginx is broken: symbol: ngx_stream_core_module

Tags: 22.04, nginx

I just encountered the same issue. I originally had 18.04 installed and first upgraded to 20.04 without problems. A day later I upgraded to 22.04 which gave me the nginx error described above.
Looking into the /etc/nginx/modules-enabled folder there were only two symbolic links:

1. 50-mod-http-geoip2.conf ->
   /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-geoip2.conf
2. 70-mod-stream-geoip2.conf ->
   /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-stream-geoip2.conf

Answer (score 0):

The reason is nginx is unable to find the core stream of nginx.

Go To /etc/nginx/modules-enabled and then run this command

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-stream.conf 50-mod-stream.conf
```

Start Nginx and problem is solved.